# Devise, all requests return 401 after updating Rails (4.1.7 to 4.1.10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Problems with Devise!

I've been messing with it all weekend to no avail, maybe one of you guys know what's up.

I can successfully create and sign in with a user returning a 201 and the all the proper stuff (user_token and email_token), however any requests after the sign_in are rejected with a 401.

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
  include AuthenticatorHelper
  # # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :after_actions

  # Use Devise to authenticate user before every action
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  private
    def id_filters
      p = params.permit(ids:[])
      return nil if p.blank?
      p[:ids].map {|x| x.to_i}
    end
end
```

The code enters the authenticate user action and then stops working. The helper I have included is this:

```
# Authenticates users by their authentication token and email if present.
# https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise#user-content-server-side-setup

module AuthenticatorHelper

  def self.included(base)
    unless base.instance_of? Module
      base.prepend_before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
    end
  end

  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      user_email = options[:user_email].presence
      user       = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

      if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, token)
        sign_in user, store: false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The Ember Application that sits above my Rails App is sending over the proper headers each time: `Token user_token="FEHR4ZpTGzsUSFvyzyKv", user_email="taylor@yolo.com"` and was not changed when I updated Rails.

Another weird thing I noticed when I entered the debugger is the `before_ filter :authenticate_user` is executed before the `sign_in` my SessionsController. And here is the code for that Controller

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { super }
      format.json do
        self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        data = {
          user_token: self.resource.authentication_token,
          user_email: self.resource.email
        }
        render json: data, status: 201
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what changes to Rails could have caused this problem? Any hunches? Could something else have caused the issue? Any guesses would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for any help on the issue, and let me know if I you want to see any more code!

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the rails update between 4.1.7 to 4.1.8.

Comment: Looks like the `:authenticate_user_from_token!` before filter is not prepended correctly. In `ApplicationController`, add `prepend_before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!`. If your code works again then something is not right with `AuthenticatorHelper#included` method.